# Emulate x86 on rasbian

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, qemu, emulation

I want to run a Starbound server on my Raspberry Pi running rasbian.
The server is built to run on an x86 architecture, so my goal is to emulate an x86 architecture to run the server.

Edit: box86 does not run 64-bit x86 binary

> To do so, I tried using [box86](https://github.com/ptitSeb/box86).
> It allowed to run a x86 program (steamcmd the program that allowed me to download the server).
> But running the server resulted in
>
> ```
> bash: ./program: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
> ```
>
> It's strange because box86 should emulate x86 program when encountered.

I tried using qemu to emulate the server.

```
sudo apt install qemu-user qemu-system qemu
sudo qemu-x86_64 starbound_server
```

Resulting in

```
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory
```

It seems like some dynamic library are missing.
I thought that those libraries would be shipped with qemu, so I tried to use the `-L` argument to specify a different ld- file.
But it seems like the program only look at the /lib64 folder.
My last try was to create this folder using lib files from an x86 system.
But this results in

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-${PLATFORM}.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

To fix this problem, people suggest to change `/etc/ld.so.preload` to remove the reference to `libarmmem`, but this file does not exist on the rasbian system.

I'd like to know if there is a better way to emulate the x86 program?
If there is none, where to find the appropriate libraries to fill the /lib64 folder?

Here are some infos I got with readelf.

```
machine: Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
type: EXEC
class: ELF64
```

Shared libraries

```
[libpthread.so.0]
[libdl.so.2]
librt.so.1]
[libm.so.6]
[libc.so.6]
[ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

Comment: Qemu doesn't ship with any system libraries, it just simulates a different CPU architecture.  Typically you use this with a chroot environment.  The chroot environment provides the libraries, qemu just translates one CPU instruction set into another.

Comment: Box86 only runs 32-bit x86 programs. The program you are trying to run on it apparently is a 64-bit x86_64 binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Stephen Kitt in the comments.

Using `chroot` and [this tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/fr/Chroot) solved the problem.

Creating a directory with a 64-bit debian.

```
apt install binutils debootstrap
mkdir my-directory
debootstrap --arch amd64 stretch my-directory http://deb.debian.org/debian
```

Then installing `qemu` in the environment.

```
chroot my-directory
apt install qemu qemu-system
```

Then to run the program anytime

```
chroot my-directory
qemu-x86_64 my_x86_programm
```

Comment: After running `chroot my-directory`, I get 
`chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: Exec format error`. Do you know what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Copy the bash executable into the chroot directory: `cp /bin/bash my-directory/bin/bash`

Comment: I had to add --foreign:

`debootstrap --foreign --arch amd64 buster my-directory http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian`

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this using QEMU 5.2, and needed a solution that would work without a chroot.  I found that if I had x86_64 libraries (libc, ld-linux-x86_64.so.2, etc) installed in /some_path that I could do:

```
ln -s . /some_path/lib64
```

and then could use:

```
qemu-static-x86_64 -L /some_path <command to run>
```

I also had to set:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/some_path
```

but that may be due to my specific environment.

Also, as I was using Centos7 where qemu-user isn't available (for aarch64), I was able to grab the debian qemu-user-static .deb from https://packages.debian.org/sid/main/qemu-user-static and use

```
ar x <deb file>
tar -xf data.tar.xz
```

And then use the resulting qemu-static* binaries since they are statically linked.  I did have to install the x86_64 libraries of course.

Answer (score 0):

Just ideas, as I have not tried it.

`/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory` is caused by libraries not installed.

You will need to add the libraries for the foreign architecture.

In debian, there is a multiarch package that (if I remember correct) manages this. The forign architecture can be pulled from the Debian repos: Same place that your OS gets its other packages.

You may need to use chroot / mount name-spaces, to avoid library mix up.

Comment: Unfortunately, AFAICT the Raspberry Pi OS archives don’t include x86 binaries, so multiarch won’t work here. The Debian repositories aren’t involved.

Comment: @StephenKitt is there a real Debian distro, or else use docker or ...